# When i am executing the code i am getting a System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i am executing the code i am getting the exception in frmtime is

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array

```
public IList<ExamSeatAllotmentEntity> GetAttendence1(string frmtime, string totime, DateTime date, int RoomNo)
{
    List<ExamSeatAllotmentEntity> ObjTestList = new List<ExamSeatAllotmentEntity>();


    //List<QuestionTypeEntity> ObjQTList = new List<QuestionTypeEntity>();
    SqlParameter[] Parms = new SqlParameter[1];
    Parms[0] = new SqlParameter("@RoomNo", SqlDbType.Int);
    Parms[0].Value = RoomNo;
    Parms[1] = new SqlParameter("@FromTime", SqlDbType.Time);
    Parms[1].Value = frmtime;
    Parms[2] = new SqlParameter("@Totime", SqlDbType.Time);
    Parms[2].Value = totime;
    Parms[3] = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    Parms[3].Value = date;


    DataSet dsTest = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlHelper.connString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, SQL_PROC_GET_Attendence1, Parms);
    if (dsTest != null && dsTest.Tables.Count == 1)
    {
        ObjTestList = (from test in dsTest.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                       select new ExamSeatAllotmentEntity()
                       {
                           // CourseID = test.Field<int>("CourseID"),
                           StudentId = test.Field<int>("StudentId"),

                           Fname = test.Field<string>("Fname"),
                           SeatNo = test.Field<string>("SeatNo"),
                           Attendence = test.Field<string>("Attendence")
                       }).ToList<ExamSeatAllotmentEntity>();
    }
    return ObjTestList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
new SqlParameter[1]
```

You just made an array that can only hold one item.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the problem:

```
SqlParameter[] Parms = new SqlParameter[1];
```

You are specifying a length of 1 element: `Parms[0]`

Correct the size of the array to allow 4 elements:

```
SqlParameter[] Parms = new SqlParameter[4];
```

In case you want to add more parameters, you might want to create a list and then transform via `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SqlParameter[] Parms = new SqlParameter[1];
```

to

```
SqlParameter[] Parms = new SqlParameter[4];
```